# MySQL/CUPS PDF printer for STAR TSP100 ECO

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, mysql, pdf

This is my very first attempt at Python and whilst the script works perfectly, I'd like to see if I'm missing anything obvious or doing anything particularly stupid. I think this runs on Python 2.7, but I'm not 100% sure.

**Goal:**
The goal here is to grab a task and its elements (records contain BLOB PDF data) and write them all to CUPS as a single print job for a receipt printer, starting with a plaintext header, followed by a list of PDF files and followed by a plaintext header.

Finally, the code should mark the task as printed in the database and remove all blob-data associated with the task as to prevent my database from turning into a massive waste of space. It should likewise delete the folder containing the 'downloaded' PDFs and header/footer files.

```
import os
import shutil
import MySQLdb
import cups

printername = "STARTTSP100"
dbAddress =  "nope"
dbUser = "nope"
dbPasswd = "nope"
dbDatabase = "printer"

# Connect to the Printer DB
db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host=dbAddress,
    user=dbUser,
    passwd=dbPasswd,
    db=dbDatabase
 )

curOne = db.cursor()
curOne.execute("SELECT task.id, task.header, task.footer FROM task WHERE task.printDate IS NULL ORDER BY task.regDate ASC LIMIT 5")
for row in curOne:

    printList = []

    if not os.path.exists(row[0]):
        os.makedirs(row[0])

    header = open(row[0]+"/"+row[0]+"_header.txt","w")
    header.write(row[1])
    header.close()
    printList.append(row[0]+"/"+row[0]+"_header.txt")

    curTwo = db.cursor()
    curTwo.execute("SELECT elements.id, elements.count, elements.data FROM elements WHERE task = '"+row[0]+"' ORDER BY count ASC")

    for subrow in curTwo:
        tempPdf = open(row[0]+"/"+subrow[0]+".pdf","wb")
        tempPdf.write(subrow[2])
        tempPdf.close()
        for x in range(0,subrow[1]):
            printList.append(row[0]+"/"+subrow[0]+".pdf")

    footer = open(row[0]+"/"+row[0]+"_footer.txt","w")
    footer.write(row[2])
    footer.close()
    printList.append(row[0]+"/"+row[0]+"_footer.txt")

    cups.Connection().printFiles(printername, printList, "expedition-"+row[0],{})

    curThree = db.cursor()
    curThree.execute( "UPDATE task SET printDate = NOW() WHERE id = '"+row[0]+"'" )
    curThree.close()

    curFour = db.cursor()
    curFour.execute( "UPDATE elements SET data = null WHERE task = '"+row[0]+"'" )
    curFour.close()

    shutil.rmtree(row[0])

db.commit()
db.close()

print("done")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put the configuration of user, password, host, etc into a dictionary. This allows you to load this dictionary from a file, if you don't want to have the password in the code. It makes it also easy to pass it to a db `connect` function:

```
# Hard-coded here, but might as well be retrieved from a config file
CONF = {'host': "nope",
        'user': "nope",
        'passwd': "nope",
        'db': "printer"}


def connect(**conf):
    """# Connect to the Printer DB"""
    return MySQLdb.connect(**conf)


db = connect(**conf)
```

The `connect` function is even transparent, so you can also pass additional keyword-arguments:

```
db = connect(raise_on_warnings=True, **conf)
```

---

I would split up the main part of the code into separate functions. One to create the files to print, which returns the list of files to print. And a second function for printing that task and cleaning up the task.

The first function is `to_print`. It yields (instead of returning the list) the files to print (as a list) for every task. Note that I re-used the `cursor`, since there is no need to create a new one every time.

I also defined a `partial` function using `functools`, which makes creating a file_name following the format `task_id/file_name` a bit easier. I also used `str.format` to avoid potentially costly string additions (I don't know how large your task_ids are.

In addition I used tuple unpacking to give `row[0]`, `row[1]` and `row[2]` meaningful names.

And finally, you should use `with..as` to automatically close a file after you are finished with it.

```
def to_print(db):
    sub_query = "SELECT elements.id, elements.count, elements.data FROM elements WHERE task = '%s' ORDER BY count ASC"

    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT task.id, task.header, task.footer FROM task WHERE task.printDate IS NULL ORDER BY task.regDate ASC LIMIT 5")
    for task_id, header, footer in cursor:
        path_join = functools.partial(os.path.join, task_id)
        print_list = []
        if not os.path.exists(task_id):
            os.makedirs(task_id)

        header_file_name = "{}_header.txt".format(path_join(task_id))
        with open(header_file_name, "w") as header_file:
            header_file.write(header)
        print_list.append(header_file_name)

        cursor2 = db.cursor()
        cursor2.execute(sub_query, (task_id,))
        for file_name, elements_count, data in cursor2:
            pdf_file_name = "{}.pdf".format(path_join(file_name))
            with open(pdf_file_name, "wb") as pdf_file:
                pdf_file.write(data)
            print_list.extend([pdf_file_name for _ in range(elements_count)])
        cursor2.close()

        footer_file_name = "{}_footer.txt".format(path_join(task_id))
        with open(footer_file_name, "w") as footer_file:
            footer_file.write(footer)
        print_list.append(footer_file_name)

        yield task_id, print_list
    cursor.close()
```

---

The second function marks a task as finished:

```
def mark_finished(db, task_id):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "UPDATE task SET printDate = NOW() WHERE id = '%s'", (task_id,))
    cursor.execute(
        "UPDATE elements SET data = null WHERE task = '%s'", (task_id,))
    cursor.close()
    shutil.rmtree(task_id)
```

It is basically the same as before, only now I re-use the cursor and use the functionality of `cursor.execute` that you can give it data in the sprintf-like format `"name: %s" % ("Graipher",)`.

---

Finally, I would put the code calling all of this in a `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard to allow importing you module from another script.

Here is also the usage of the generator returned by `to_print`, we just iterate over the tasks. The actual printing is inlined here, you could also stick it into a function.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = connect(**CONF)
    for task_id, print_list in to_print(db):
        cups.Connection().printFiles(PRINTER, print_list, "expedition-" + task_id, {})
        mark_finished(db, task_id)
    db.commit()
    db.close()

    print("done")
```

---

This can be broken down into even smaller tasks (the writing of the files is still some-what redundant for example), which I did in my **final code:**

```
import os
import shutil
import MySQLdb
import cups
import functools
from contextlib import closing

PRINTER = "STARTTSP100"

# Hard-coded here, but might as well be retrieved from a config file
CONF = {'host': "nope",
        'user': "nope",
        'passwd': "nope",
        'db': "printer"}


def connect(**conf):
    """# Connect to the Printer DB"""
    return MySQLdb.connect(**conf)


def create_file(task_id, extension, data):
    file_name = "{}{}".format(os.path.join(task_id, task_id), extension)
    with open(file_name, "w") as write_file:
        write_file.write(data)
    return file_name


def create_files(db, task_id, query):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, task_id)
    for file_name, elements_count, data in cursor:
        pdf_file_name = "{}.pdf".format(os.path.join(task_id, file_name))
        with open(pdf_file_name, "wb") as pdf_file:
            pdf_file.write(data)
        yield [pdf_file_name for _ in range(elements_count)]
    cursor.close()


def to_print(db):
    with db as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT task.id, task.header, task.footer FROM task WHERE task.printDate IS NULL ORDER BY task.regDate ASC LIMIT 5")

        sub_query = "SELECT elements.id, elements.count, elements.data FROM elements WHERE task = '%s' ORDER BY count ASC"

        for task_id, header, footer in cursor:
            if not os.path.exists(task_id):
                os.makedirs(task_id)

            print_list = [create_file(task_id, "_header.txt", header)]

            for files in create_files(db, task_id, sub_query):
                print_list.extend(files)

            print_list.append(create_file(task_id, "_footer.txt", footer))

            yield task_id, print_list


def mark_finished(db, task_id):
    with db as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            "UPDATE task SET printDate = NOW() WHERE id = '%s'", task_id)
        cursor.execute(
            "UPDATE elements SET data = null WHERE task = '%s'", task_id)
    shutil.rmtree(task_id)


def print_files(print_list, name, printer=PRINTER)
    cups.Connection().printFiles(printer, print_list, name, {})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with closing(connect(**CONF)) as db:
        for task_id, print_list in to_print(db):
            print_files(print_list, "expedition-" + task_id)
            mark_finished(db, task_id)    
    print("done")
```

Note the addition of `contextlib.closing` to ensure that the db connection is closed even if an exception is raised somewhere in-between and using `with db as cursor` to make sure the `cursor` is also closed and comitted.

Comment: Thanks @Graipher! This was very extensive and I think I've learned a whole bunch of new stuff about Python.

Comment: @NicholasC You're welcome. Since I don't have a MySQL db set up right now, I couldn't test the code. There might be some typos left in there somewhere. Note that I edited the answer and added more automatic closing (of the db connection and the cursors), which will make sure that all connections are closed if some line in-between raises an exception.

Comment: I'm a bit caught up till the weekend, then I'll dive in and give it some rigorous testing. I'll let you know if any typos pop up. Thanks again!